# Predict based on lag(prediction)?

Tags: r

(Tag suggestions welcome, included dplyr only since I'm using dplyr::lag)

A poor example that nevertheless illustrates the question / need:

```
example_df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5
) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative = x + lag(x), 
         somepredictor = rnorm(5))

# very bad example, I would not do this in real life
mod <- lm(cumulative ~ lag(cumulative), data = example_df)
```

With this model, how could I predict on new data? The catch is that I need the prediction from the previous row as an input to the current prediction, so regular old `predict(newdf)` won't do.

Is there a way that I can predict based on a lag in this way?

Comment: E.g. by a for loop.

Comment: Funny I posted on SO and they told me to migrate it over here.

Comment: A common approach is to do "rolling predictions": In Step 1, you would predict the next value. Then, the lagged variables are recalculated based on that prediction (with or without noise) and the historical data. Then, you predict the next value etc. How many time to repeat this process depends on the number of steps to be predicted and the lag orders. The further ahead, the less precise the predictions because part of the covariables have been predicted as well. But this is a problem with most forecast methods. This is why I proposed to use a `for` loop ;).